# Getting objects from a window Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

What's the best way to get objects from a window. I have a sudoku-like grid of 81 NSTextFields and I would prefer to simply have an array of NSTextFields instead of 81 individual NSTextFields linked through IBOutlets. 
For example: if there was a way to send a message to NSWindow such as getObject: (NSString*) title and then use a for-loop to add these NSTextFields to an NSMutableArray, that would be ideal.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

-Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
NSArray *subviews = [_window subViews];
for(NSView *subview in subviews)
{
  if( [subview isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]] )
  {
     [_textFields addObject:subview];
  }
}
```

in -awakeFromNib

Now for the nagging, I don't think you should do it this way. Creating a custom NSView to act as a "Sudoku" view would be both easier to use in your code and better for performance of your application. Loading the Window with 81 textFields is quite heavy + uses a lot more memory.

Comment: Ok, no problem there, I was about to put this in another view and add a view controller to make it more modular and scalable anyway. I just wanted to know if I could get an object directly from the window/view instead of using IBOutlets. Thanks! -Luke

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you would be much better off with an [NSMatrix](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004060) of NSTextFieldCells.

A matrix is a single object that you can reference with a single outlet connection (or other property), and it knows about rows and columns (so no need to convert those to and from linear indexes). You can also access its individual cells to configure them separately; for example, to set the filled-in values and disable those cells so the user can't change them.